# I am facing the problem using the chronometer and progress-bar inside the android notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications

I am working on implementing a custom Android notification with a chronometer and progress bar inside a RemoteView using a custom layout. The implementation works as expected in normal scenarios, but I am facing issues when the user closes or kills the application. In such cases, both the Android chronometer and progress bar are not behaving as expected.

In my recent implementation, I am using a sticky notification. Here is a snippet of the code:

```kotlin
val expandedNotifView = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.custom_notification_id27)

expandedNotifView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_content_title3, heading)
expandedNotifView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_content_text3, content)
expandedNotifView.setViewVisibility(R.id.productImageView_large, View.VISIBLE)
expandedNotifView.setViewVisibility(R.id.rlFlipper, View.GONE)
expandedNotifView.setViewVisibility(R.id.viewFlipperLarge, View.GONE)
expandedNotifView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.productImageView_large, img)

val imgIntent =
    GcmIntentService.setSlotIntentTemplate(
        context,
        uuid,
        link,
        GcmIntentService.CTA_ACTION_TEMPLATE_27,
        tId,
        "",
        "0",
        fullImg
    )

imgIntent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationId)

val contentIntentimg =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId, imgIntent, getImmutableFlagOrNone())

expandedNotifView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.productImageView_large, contentIntentimg)

mBuilder.setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())

val collapsedView = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.custom_notification_id27_collapsed)

collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_content_title3, heading)
collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_content_text3, content)
collapsedView.setViewVisibility(R.id.downArrowImg, View.VISIBLE)
collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_content_title3, heading)
collapsedView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_content_text3, content)

val contentIntentNext =
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, clickIntentNext, getImmutableFlagOrNone())

expandedNotifView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgNext, contentIntentNext)
expandedNotifView.setViewVisibility(R.id.imgNext, View.VISIBLE)

collapsedView.setViewVisibility(R.id.imgNext, View.VISIBLE)

expandedNotifView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgPrev, contentIntentPrev)
expandedNotifView.setViewVisibility(R.id.imgPrev, View.VISIBLE)

collapsedView.setViewVisibility(R.id.imgPrev, View.VISIBLE)

val date = format.parse(exptime)
val elapsed = now.time - date.time

// long secs = now.getTime() - date.getTime();
val remainingTime = startTime - elapsed

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    collapsedView.setChronometerCountDown(R.id.myChronometere, true)
    expandedNotifView.setChronometerCountDown(R.id.myChronometere, true)
}

collapsedView.setChronometer(R.id.myChronometere, remainingTime, "%tH:%tM:%tS", true)
expandedNotifView.setChronometer(R.id.myChronometere, remainingTime, "%tH:%tM:%tS", true)
collapsedView.setViewVisibility(R.id.myChronometere, View.VISIBLE)
expandedNotifView.setViewVisibility(R.id.myChronometere, View.VISIBLE)

val notifications =
    NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.material_sd_notificationicon)
        .setColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.notificationb_bg_color))
        .setContentTitle(heading)
        .setContentText(content)
        .setCustomContentView(collapsedView)
        .setCustomBigContentView(expandedNotifView)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setOngoing(true)

mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notifications.build())
```

Comment: "are not behaving as expected" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What are your expectations? What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I have tried to implement a solution, but I am facing issues with the chronometer and progress bar when the application is closed or killed. Please suggest the best approach or provide corrections to my existing implementation.

I am looking to achieve a UI similar to the screenshot below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQDUV.png

Comment: did you find the solution for this, I am facing the same problem. In my case chronometer is running fine but its showing negative value after it reaches 00:00:00. To overcome that I used Handler to remove the notification once we reach at 0 but that doesnt work if app is in killed state.